# How can I access SceneKit files downloaded from Firebase?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, scenekit, arkit

- I have an ARKit app that uses image recognition to trigger SceneKit/3D Object files, specifically for art exhibitions. 
  I've recently began implementing Firebase Storage in order to reduce the overall download size and rather download the 3D files on demand, per which exhibition the user is using!

I've successfully set up the app to download the SceneKit files to the mobile storage, but where I am stuck now is figuring out how to read the file from the specific downloaded location and continue working it in the image recognition/AR process accordingly.

Before, when the Scenekit files were included in the initial download via Scenekit Catalog in the app folder, I would read them like so:

```
   let ShipScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")
```

Now, I've updated it to read the same string as the download URL, but the image recognition is not working.

I assume my problem is that it is not reading the right location, or I may be using the wrong function. I've put the app through to my phone through TestFlight and still no luck.

```
// Downloading from firebase to device URL

  let shipURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/QZ_Gallery/SceneKitFiles/ship.scn", isDirectory: true)


 let shipDownload = shipRef.write(toFile: shipURL)

 // Attempting to pull the file from the downloaded location

 let ShipScene = SCNScene(named:"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/QZ_Gallery/SceneKitFiles/ship.scn" )
```

*** My question is in the final line of code I included. I am trying to make sure I am searching in the right place to retrieve the files that were downloaded, or if the function I am using is even proper for retrieving files stored locally on a mobile device.

Comment: Super interesting project. The question is a bit unclear though... Do you upload the .scn files to Firebase Storage and then store that URL path in Firebase Realtime Database? Then when you want to retrieve the stored file, are you getting the URL path from Firebase Real Time Database and then downloading the file from storage? If so, have you walked through that code looking for issues and can you include the code that's not working? Please review the following [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity -  I uploaded the .scn files straight to Firebase Storage through the Firebase website, did not use Firebase Database/Firebase Realtime Database as I was told they cannot directly host raw .scn files. I am directly downloading from the Storage into the mobile device (the URL is the download location)   --  I've looked at the device container to confirm the download is working. The issue is now reading the .scn file from the downloaded location, which is what I'm attempting to do in the final line of code.

Comment: *I was told they cannot directly host raw .scn files* which is correct. However, the RTDB is the perfect place to store the URL path's for easy access. That's really the best solution; upload the files to storage in your app, keep track of the URL files in the RTDB and when you need them, grab the paths from RTDB and download the .scn files. It's a pretty seamless solution. See the docs [Upload From A Local File](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file) and store the download path in RTDB.

Comment: Well, it appears I totally misunderstood the question, my apologies. You are simply asking how to access a file (that you downloaded) from your local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by first adding a function to find the scenepath of the container which has all my scenes, and then using the scene path in the fetching of the individual .scn file. Scene downloads from Firebase Storage (No use of Realtime Database) and integrates properly with the image recognition.

```
      let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

                  let scenePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("Scenes")
                  if(!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: scenePath.absoluteString)) {
                      do {
                          try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: scenePath.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                          } catch {
                              print(error.localizedDescription);
                          }
                  }

           // Start Download, writing to a file




        let sceneURL = scenePath.appendingPathComponent("Ship.scn", isDirectory: true)
```